# Print train with characters

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I am trying to find a good way to print a train in Java by using characters.

```
     ++      +------
     ||      |+-+ | 
   /---------|| | | 
  + ========  +-+ | 
 _|--/~\------/~\-+ 
//// \_/      \_/
```

**My solution approach so far:**

- Using a String array and saving line by line.

e.g.

```
String[] array = new String[10];
array[0] = "...";
array[1] = "...";
...
```

Another idea was to use `StringBuilder`.

Is there a better way than using `StringBuilder`?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `sl` library: https://github.com/mtoyoda/sl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can drastically simplify the way you create the array:

```
final String[] train = {
    "     ++      +------",
    "     ||      |+-+ | ",
    "   /---------|| | | ",
    "  + ========  +-+ | ",
    " _|--/~\\------/~\\-+ ",
    "//// \\_/      \\_/   "

};
```

And then either print this line by line, or `String.join` it first.

Comment: Like this ```String result = String.join(Arrays.toString(train));```?

Comment: Also, I am getting the error message "Illegal escape character in string literal" for the last two lines. Do you have an idea how to fix that? I am relatively new to this topic.

Comment: @LudwigvonDrake `\ ` needs to be escaped, replacing every occurance of `\ ` with `\\ ` should fix it

Comment: @LudwigvonDrake No, `Arrays.toString` isn’t correct here. `String.join` needs two parameters, the array as well as the string you want to use as a joiner. You would want to use `System.lineSeparator()` for that.

Answer (score 2):

In the future, Java will feature Text Blocks (https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/355). You can already use them in JDK 13 as a preview feature.

Using Text Blocks you could write something like:

```
String train = """
                   ++      +------
                   ||      |+-+ | 
                 /---------|| | | 
                + ========  +-+ | 
               _|--/~\------/~\-+ 
              //// \_/      \_/
              """;
```

Comment: need to use both compile time and run time command line arguments to enable the preview feature

Comment: Unfortunately, I am only allowed to use Java 8 for this project.

Answer (score 2):

To support both Windows and Linux line separators (`\r\n` vs `\n`), using `%n` with `printf`:

```
System.out.printf("     ++      +------%n" + 
                  "     ||      |+-+ | %n" + 
                  "   /---------|| | | %n" + 
                  "  + ========  +-+ | %n" + 
                  " _|--/~\\------/~\\-+ %n" + 
                  "//// \\_/      \\_/  %n");
```

It will compile the same as:

```
System.out.printf("     ++      +------%n     ||      |+-+ | %n   /---------|| | | %n  + ========  +-+ | %n _|--/~\\------/~\\-+ %n//// \\_/      \\_/  %n");
```

*Output*

```
     ++      +------
     ||      |+-+ | 
   /---------|| | | 
  + ========  +-+ | 
 _|--/~\------/~\-+ 
//// \_/      \_/
```

Answer (score 2):

Forget about static train, do moving train :)

Java 11+

```java
package org.pta.train;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static final int FRAME_TIME = 300;
    public static final int CARS_COUNT = 10;

    public static final List<String> TRAIN = List.of(
            "            ".repeat(CARS_COUNT) + " . . . . . o o o o o      ",
            "___________ ".repeat(CARS_COUNT) + "_______    ____      o    ",
            "[] [] [] [] ".repeat(CARS_COUNT) + "[_____(__  ][]]_n_n__][.  ",
            "[_________]_".repeat(CARS_COUNT) + "[________]_|__|________)< ",
            "oo      oo '".repeat(CARS_COUNT) + " oo    oo 'oo 0000---oo\\_"
    );

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        clearConsole();

        for (int i = 0; i < TRAIN.get(0).length(); i++) {
            printFrame(i);

            Thread.sleep(FRAME_TIME);

            clearConsole();
        }
    }

    private static void clearConsole() {
        System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
    }

    private static void printFrame(int i) {
        System.out.println(TRAIN.stream()
                .map(line -> line.substring(line.length() - i))
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
    }
}
```

P.S.: There might be an issues with `clearConsole()` if you'll run it form IDE, but it should work fine from cmd :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this is the prev answer. But If you want it to compile you need to escape `\`.

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String[] train = {
            "     ++      +------",
            "     ||      |+-+ | ",
            "   /---------|| | | ",
            "  + ========  +-+ | ",
            " _|--/~\\------/~\\-+ ",
            "//// \\_/      \\_/   "

    };

    System.out.println(String.join(System.lineSeparator(), train));
}
```

And this is Java 8 only :)

Comment: so basically, a duplicate of an existing answer. should be mentioned as comment

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Cannot agee. Fully working code provided.

Comment: Replace `"\n"` with `System.lineSeparator()` so it uses ``\r\n`` on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend to use this designs in the code, instead for a clean solution, I would suggest to create txt files for your designs and then just read them :

### Design file

[image: train design]

### Code to read your design

```
public static void printDesign(String designName) {
    Path filePath = Paths.get(String.format("D:\\%s.txt", designName));

    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(filePath)) {
        lines.forEach(System.out::println);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and then call your method :

```
printDesign("train");
```

It print for me :

[image: design]

Answer (score -1):

I would put the whole drawing into a text file. That way you don't need to hassle with escaping special char and stuff. You can read the whole file into `List` of Strings in one line using [`Files.readAllLines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset))